# Get Text from RadioButtons using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

this is my radiobutton set.

```
<div id="radio" align="center">        
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioService" /><label for="radio1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioService" /><label for="radio2">Option 2</label>         
</div>
```

And this is what I've tried.

```
var radio = $('input[name=radioService]:checked', '#form1').val();
```

After firebugging a bit, I got this:

When NONE radio was selected: `undefined`
When one of them was selected: `on`

What I need to get is my variable to become "option 1" or "option 2", or in case none of them are selected a null or an empty space " ".

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Using jquery 191

Comment: set value of check box input like `<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioService" value ="option1" />` and get value using `$("#form1 input[name=radioService]:checked").val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var radio = $('input[name=radioService]:checked', '#form1').next('label').text();
console.log(radio);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FE74D/)

Comment: Why do all this round-about work when you can just set the value of the radio option and retrieve it with `.val()`?

Comment: @Willem Ellis you are right if we set value then its more faster then take text from next label

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting a value for your radio options. You want something like this:

```
<div id="radio" align="center">        
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioService" value="Option 1"/><label for="radio1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioService" value="Option 2"/><label for="radio2">Option 2</label>         
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle of it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/m47wX/1/)

Comment: @WillemEllis will mark Palash answer as the one just because he did it 2 mins quicker. But thanks a lot, it was one or the other, upvoted already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `length` to check if none is selected

```
var selectedRadio = $('input[name=radioServicio]:checked', '#form1');    
radio = "";
if(selectedRadio.length)    
  radio = selectedRadio.val();    
else
  radio = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no value assigned to rabiobutton input tags, try this:

```
<div id="radio" align="center">        
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioService" value="val1"/><label for="radio1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioService" value="val2" /><label for="radio2">Option 2</label>         
</div>
```